# I am multithreading a operation in python to make it faster but it is still not faster

Tags: python, multithreading

This is the program below but I am confused the multithreaded program runs slower when compared to the program which is not multithreaded. What could be the reason. Why multithreading is slower than single thread (main thread) computation??

```
import numpy as np
from threading import *
from functools import reduce
import time

#Multithreading
l = list(range(1,10001))
b = []
b1 = []
c = []
c1 = []
a = []
d = []
d1 = []
start_time = time.time()
print("######### with multithreading##########")
class ta1(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global b
        b = l[0:2500]
        b = list(map(lambda x: x*x ,b))
class ta2(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global b1
        b1 = l[2500:5000]
        b1 = list(map(lambda x: x*x ,b1))
class ta3(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global d
        d = l[5000:7500]
        d = list(map(lambda x: x*x ,b1))
class ta4(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global d1
        d1 = l[7500:10001]
        d1 = list(map(lambda x: x*x ,b1))
t1 = ta1()
t2 = ta2()
t3 = ta3()
t4 = ta4()
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
a = [*b,*b1,*d,*d1]
print(a)
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)

print('########### normal without threading ############')
xc = time.time()
c = list(map(lambda x:x*x,l))
print(c)
xc1 = time.time()
print(xc1-xc)
```

And the output time for both was

```
######### with  multithreading##########

0.7726929187774658
########### normal without threading ############

0.5661568641662598
```

Comment: Python cannot more than one thread in parallel because of the [GIL](https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-13-the-gil-and-its-effects-on-python-multithreading/). Multithreading is only useful when some threads are blocking on i/o; they will not help a CPU-bound program run in parallel.

Comment: This isn't an operation that's likely to benefit from multithreading since it's spending all its time in the interpreter in a single process.  I'd hazard a guess that it's slower in the multithreaded version because you're allocating the input list (`b = l[0:2500]` etc) as part of the computation in the multithreaded version, whereas in the single-threaded version you create the input list before starting the timer.

Answer (score 0):

As @larsks stated, Python does not support running multiple threads in parallel. This makes it slower to use threading, as setting up the threads slows down the program.